include additional columns when aggregating overlapping time intervals
I have a table with user ID, as well as multiple Start Dates and End Dates for each ID, which sometimes overlap.  I need to capture each period of start/end time by ID, with multiple rows if there are lapses between date blocks. Thanks to this post  and the code by horseyride, I have been able to show the start/end dates as expected.  However, in addition to the ID, StartMin, and EndMax fields, I also need to include other text fields/columns that are located in the same row/record for each EndMax row/record.  My various attempts to include these fields have instead given me the cells that are located in the StartMin rows, or in other cases have randomly given back cells that are not always accurate (sometimes the data from the EndMax rows, but occasionally not).
My data:



ID
StartDate
EndDate
Reason
Area
Jurisdiction




123
06/17/23
06/20/23
AA
ZZ
1


123
06/17/23
01/23/24
BB
YY
2


123
06/17/23
04/09/24
Order-0
0-OC
3


456
06/11/20
06/13/20
CC
XX
1


456
02/07/21
02/08/21
DD
WW
2


456
02/07/21
02/08/21
EE
VV
3


456
05/19/22
08/29/22
FF
UU
4


456
06/26/22
07/11/22
GG
TT
5


456
06/26/22
07/12/22
HH
SS
6


456
06/26/22
09/08/22
II
RR
7


456
06/26/22
09/08/22
Order-5
5-OC
8


789
09/30/19
12/17/19
JJ
QQ
1


789
12/05/20
12/08/20
KK
PP
2


789
03/11/21
04/08/21
LL
OO
3


789
03/11/21
03/17/22
MM
NN
4


789
05/04/22
10/27/22
NN
MM
5


789
05/04/22
01/31/23
OO
LL
6


789
01/25/23
03/12/23
PP
KK
7


789
02/10/23
12/19/23
Transfer
DS-DT
8


789
03/21/23
03/22/23
QQ
JJ
9


789
05/12/23
12/14/23
RR
II
10



My expected results without pulling in the (EndMax row) Reason/Area/Jurisdiction using my existing M code:



ID
StartMin
EndMax




123
6/17/2023
4/9/2024


456
6/11/2020
6/13/2020


456
2/7/2021
2/8/2021


456
5/19/2022
9/8/2022


789
9/30/2019
12/17/2019


789
12/5/2020
12/8/2020


789
3/11/2021
3/17/2022


789
5/4/2022
12/19/2023



My desired results, to include the Reason/Area/Jurisdiction columns/data from the EndMax rows:



ID
StartDate
EndDate
Reason
Area
Jurisdiction
x




123
06/17/23
04/09/24
Order-0
0-OC
3



456
06/11/20
06/13/20
CC
XX
1



456
02/07/21
02/08/21
DD
WW
2
or   02/08/2021  EE  VV  3


456
05/19/22
09/08/22
Order-5
5-OC
8



789
09/30/19
12/17/19
JJ
QQ
1



789
12/05/20
12/08/20
KK
PP
2



789
03/11/21
03/17/22
MM
NN
4



789
05/04/22
12/19/23
Transfer
DS-DT
8




M code for existing 2 queries:
process query
(xtable)=>
// compare each list against all lists in column Custom, and merge those that overlap
let Source= Table.Buffer(xtable),
#"Added Custom"= Table.AddColumn( 
     Source,
    "Custom2",
        each List.Accumulate (
         Source[Custom],
         [Custom],
        (state,current)=> if List.ContainsAny(state,current) then List.Distinct(List.Combine({current,state})) else state
    )
),
// count the number of changes made from original version. If this is not zero, we will recurse the changes
x= List.Sum(List.Transform(List.Positions(#"Added Custom"[Custom]), each if #"Added Custom"[Custom]{_} = #"Added Custom"[Custom2]{_} then 0 else 1)),
RemovePrioCustom= Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
AddNewCustom= Table.RenameColumns(RemovePrioCustom,{{"Custom2", "Custom"}}),
recursive = if x=0 then AddNewCustom else @process( AddNewCustom)
in recursive

Table1 query

let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"StartDate", type date}, {"EndDate", type date}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type" , {"ID"}, {{"data", each 
let  #"AddIndex" = Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Round1" = Table.AddColumn(#"AddIndex", "Custom",  (i)=>Table.SelectRows(#"AddIndex", each 
    ([EndDate]=null and (i[EndDate]=null or [StartDate]<=i[EndDate])) or //remove this row if you don't care about null dates to speed things up
     ([StartDate]>=i[StartDate] and [StartDate]<=i[EndDate]) or 
    ([StartDate]<=i[StartDate] and [EndDate]>=i[StartDate])
     )[Index]),
#"Round2"= process(#"Round1"),
#"GetStart" = Table.AddColumn(#"Round2", "StartMin", each List.Min(List.Transform([Custom], each #"Round2"[StartDate]{_})),type date),
#"GetEnd"= Table.AddColumn(#"GetStart", "EndMax", each 
    let a=List.Transform([Custom], each #"GetStart"[EndDate]{_})
    in if List.Count(a)-List.NonNullCount(a) > 0 then null else List.Max(a)),
#"RemoveColumns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"GetEnd",{"StartDate", "EndDate", "Index", "Custom"}),
#"CleanUp" = Table.Distinct(#"RemoveColumns", {"ID", "StartMin", "EndMax"})
in #"CleanUp", type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"StartMin", "EndMax"}, {"StartMin", "EndMax"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded data",{{"ID", Order.Ascending}, {"StartMin", Order.Ascending}, {"EndMax", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows",{{"StartMin", type date}, {"EndMax", type date}})
in #"Changed Type1"


Just merge it in at the end
Add steps at end that creates a new column for both source table and ending table, which contains ID merged with EndDate. Then do a merge on the new column/new table to new column/old table . Edit merged results column so each table has one row only. Expand.  Here, assuming that the data starts with Source and last step was #"Last Step"
#"Last Step" = ....
before = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Text.From([ID])&Text.From(Number.From([EndDate]))),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Last Step", "Custom", each Text.From([ID])&Text.From(Number.From([EndMax]))),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom", {"Custom"}, before, {"Custom"}, "before", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
FirstRowOnly = Table.TransformColumns(#"Merged Queries",{{"before", each Table.FirstN(_,1)}}),
#"Expanded" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(FirstRowOnly, "before", {"Reason", "Area", "Jurisdiction"}, {"Reason", "Area", "Jurisdiction"})
in #"Expanded"



Getting close now ;)
